# How to simultaneously change the value of one seekbar based on other

Tags: android, seekbar

Have three seekbars on one Activity. All of them have max of 100. I need to sum of all three was 100.

When *seek1*=50 and *seek2*=45 then *seek3* must be 5.
When I slide *seek1* to 55 *seek3* must have 0. etc.

How can I code this?

Sorry, here is my code:

```
//01
   final SeekBar seekBar01 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek01);
            final TextView seekBar01Value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt01val);
            seekBar01.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    seekBar01Value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
    //02
            SeekBar seekBar02 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek02);
            final TextView seekBar02Value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt02val);
            seekBar02.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    seekBar02Value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });

//03
            SeekBar seekBar03 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek03);
            final TextView seekBar03Value = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt03val);
            seekBar03.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    seekBar03Value.setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                }

                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

                }
            });
```

I can show values on respective TextViews, but don't get how to change another seebar progress from other seekbar onProgressChanged.

Comment: Are you stuck on the logic or the `SeekBar` code? Show what you have done so far.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service, but people are willing to help you if you at least try to solve the problem at your own. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Then, update and improve your *question*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trouble was because of late declarations of SeekBar's.
If gather all SeekBar seekBarXX = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekXX); sooner than Change listeners all works as expected.
Sorry for stupidity.
Here is code:

```
final SeekBar seekBar01 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek01);
final SeekBar seekBar02 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek02);
final SeekBar seekBar03 = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seek03);

seekBar01.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {                   
                seekBar02.setProgress(100-seekBar01.getProgress());
            }
...
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [OnSeekBarChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener.html) to your seekbars. When one changes, set the values to the others with `setProgress`